# Magento 2.1, Sanitization scripts for dev environment?

Tags: magento-2.1, database, development, script

I was wondering if anybody has developed a **SQL Sanitization script for Magento 2.1 for test/dev environment?**

To clarify, We make a copy of our production environment into a development environment periodically, and it would be useful/helpful (and safer) to have all clients/orders/invoices Sanitized of any personally identifiable information **(names, address, email address)**, without deleting those customers/orders/invoices etc.

Any suggestions/sample queries/recommendations are welcome.

Comment: i haven't used one yet as our production is still based on 1.14 EE, but one thing I did do that **drastically** reduced possible public issues is to add a whitelist to my development server's Postfix configuration.  This prevents **ANY** email being sent via sendmail from going out _unless_ it's in my "approved" list (which is just my email and my testing emails).

Comment: Sadly, that option doesn't exist in CE.

Comment: I should also mention, this wouldn't be just for email security. It would be to help prevent 3rd party support from gaining access to client data, and reduces risk exposure.  When we require 3rd party support (some extensions for example), we only give them access to our Dev site, NOT our production, this mitigates some risk, but still leaves a lot of wanted data available to too many people.  I'm going to look into creating some scripts to do just this.

Comment: Postfix is a mail server client, nothing to do with CE vs EE.  More to do with how your PHP has your mail set up.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I use a github extension that connects to our Office365 server, so that is not really an option.  Good idea though.

Comment: As a guide, for our 1.x installation, we use a custom shell script to do this.  Due to the volume of records being adjusted, we had to split it up into chunks where it will run through all customers and update their name and email to be fake addresses based on their store customer id.

Comment: You can use Postfix on the server to connect to Office365, thus eliminating a module within Magento and making it easier to "block" unwanted outgoing mailings.  I use Postfix to relay mail through my gmail account for my dev server(s).

Answer (score 0):

Please use this script https://github.com/kalpa-github/m2-db-sanitization-script.git
please do necessary changes